# What [else] does this PowerShell Command? How could I reproduce it in Java?

Tags: java, powershell, exchange-server

I want to create a web application where employees could manage their email-forwarding settings.

In the past, this happened via some PowerShell scripts. For example, setting email forward with copy:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://[server] -Authentication Kerberos
Import-PSSession $Session
Set-Mailbox -Identity "{USERNAME}" -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $true -ForwardingAddress "{EMAIL}"
```

I set the redirection and watched the Active Directory for changes. It set the parameter `altRecipient` of the original recipient to the DN of the new and the parameter `altRecipientBL` of the new recipient to the DN of the old. I tried to reproduce these parameters with JND functionalities, but it doesn't redirect the mails. So there must be more what this PowerShell Command does, maybe changing the settings of the ExchangeServer.

How could I reproduce following functionality in Java preferably without using the PowerShell?

- check forwarding status
- remove forwarding
- set forwarding with copy
- set forwarding without copy

Comment: Why don't you just invoke the powershell script from the webapp?

Comment: @Michael I tried to, but my webapp didn't execute any powershell scripts at all. at least not on the remote server where the app is supposed to run.

Comment: @Michael there is another problem with authentification. in JDN I could give credentials to the Active Directory, how could I set them before executing the script?

Answer (score 1):

`$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://[server] -Authentication Kerberos` :Creates a new remote session (via WSMAN) to the exchange server.

`Import-PSSession $Session`: Is used to import the remote Exchange cmdlets to your local machine. If you would not call `Import-PSSession`, `Set-MailBox`-cmdlet of the next line would not be available on your local machine:

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity "{USERNAME}" -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $true -ForwardingAddress "{EMAIL}"
```

From [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-pssession?view=powershell-6):

> The Import-PSSession cmdlet imports commands , such as cmdlets, functions, and aliases, from a PSSession on a local or remote computer into the current session. You can import any command that the Get-Command cmdlet can find in the PSSession. ...

Your question:

> How could I reproduce following functionality in Java preferably without using the PowerShell?

Well you've to use kind of Java remoting mechanism towards Exchange server. On the Exchange server there needs to be some endpoint that is able to call the PowerShell command.

Hope that helps.